# C++: dll not working on Visual Studio 2017 but works with g++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2017, g++

I am having this issue with more complex code, this is naturally a simplified example.

dll does not work with VS but does work with g++,

I have this code,

```
#include <stdio.h>      

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void func(int a)
{
    printf("a: %d\n", a);
}
```

This is the only file in my VS project. I compile it and VS succesfully generates a test.dll
[image: Configuration Manager]

But when I call the library (from python for example), it complains that the dll is not win32, see,

```
import os
import sys
import ctypes
import sys

file_dll = 'test.dll'
print('Using {}...'.format(file_dll),flush=True)
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(file_dll)
a=ctypes.c_int(0)
lib.func(a)
```

outputs,

```
    Using ./test.dll...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call.py", line 14, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(file_dll)
  File "..\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 434, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "..\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 356, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Now, if I compile the same code using,

```
g++ test.cpp -shared -o test2.dll
```

outputs,

```
Using test2.dll... a: 0
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you build it in VS with the "Release" configuration? Maybe Python can't (or won't) load the required support stuff for the Debug build.

Comment: Good point, but just tested and is exactly the same. Furthermore, I compiled it with debugging symbols with `g++ -g` and it also works just fine.

Comment: I believe VS requires `dllmain` function in a .cpp file to compile a .dll library. There might be other requirements.

Comment: In a different file you mean? It is strange that it compiles without complaining.

Comment: @myradio At the risk of asking the obvious, is the python process 32-bit, too?

Comment: @dxiv Obvious not so obvious, indeed that was the problem. Either if I call the 32bit dll from python 64bit or I call the 64bit dll from python 32bit I got a message that it is not a win32 application, I guess it refers to different things but I couldn't see it.
Feel free to post the answer, I will accept. Although, it was such a silly thing :P

Comment: @myradio Glad it helped. The "*Win32*" part of the error message can be confusing, indeed, though it is technically correct. I added a note about that in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error "*not a valid Win32 application*" often indicates a bitness mismatch where a 64-bit process attempts to load a 32-bit library, or the other way around. Given the posted screenshot shows the DLL being 32-bit (platform = x86) chances are the python module is 64-bit.

The "*Win32 application*" part of the error message does *not* refer to the referenced module being 32-bit (which in this case it is, indeed). Rather, "*Win32 application*" is the technical term for (native) Windows applications, regardless of the bitness of either Windows host or client application. Quoting MS from [Win32 (Windows API)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/api-index-portal):

> *The Win32 API (also called the Windows API) is the native platform for Windows apps. This API is best for desktop apps that require direct access to system features and hardware. The Windows API can be used in all desktop apps, and the same functions are generally supported on 32-bit and 64-bit Windows.*